# Using ViewState string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-parsing

```
DateTime sStartDate = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["StartDate"]));
                string sEndDate1 = Convert.ToString(ViewState["EndDate"]);
                DateTime sEndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sEndDate1, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After DateTime sEndDate its shows exception : string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: Are you trying to get around the exception if the data is not set?  Maybe use DateTime.TryParse?

Comment: What is the actual value of ViewState["EndDate"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the format to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(sEndDate1, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[The `hh` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) represents the hour as a number from 01 through 12.

If `sEndDate1` hour is ie 13:00:00 it will throw an exception because it is out of range.

Comment: Thanks that's helped me.